# Combining 2 tables

Tags: sql

Wondering if someone could help me combine (in SQL) two tables into one query. I have tried the UNION command to combine the tables, but get the error that the number of columns in the two selected tables or queries of a union query do not match. Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT [CustID], [First], [Last]
FROM Customers
WHERE [First] IN ("Angel", "Mike", "Phan")
UNION 
SELECT [PartID]
FROM Sales
WHERE [PartID] IN ("Y450T", "Y430P", "G814T");
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data and the desired outcome?

Comment: Show us the table structures, do these two tables have some relation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking what you mean to do is a `JOIN` based on evidence from your question.  If there is some column that is common between `CUSTOMERS` and `SALES` -- say `[CustID]` -- then you can join the two tables.

Something like this?

```
SELECT a.[CustID], [First], [Last], b.[PartID]
FROM Customers a
INNER JOIN Sales b
ON a.[CustID]=b.[CustID]
WHERE [First] IN ("Angel", "Mike", "Phan")
AND [PartID] IN ("Y450T", "Y430P", "G814T")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however the error message that came up is "Type mismatch in expression". I am sorry I didn't mention before but I am running SQL in Microsoft Access 2013.

Comment: @user3501263 -- yeah, that woulda been a good thing to mention up front.

Comment: OK, I am sorry for that as I am learning SQL for the first time. Are you able to help with my question or not? And I appreciate the help you have given me so far, thank you.